# AngularJS : How to pass data from directive to controllers function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to pass some data from directive into a function `addTrackFromPicker` in my controller.

```
$scope.addTrackFromPicker = function (message) {
    console.log("addTrackFromPicker", message);
};
```

Here what I have in my directive

```
dir.directive('youtubeList', function($http, $timeout, YT_event){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            search: '=',
            dial: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'youtube-list.html',
...
```

Here I want to call controllers function from my template and pass it `item.id.$t` as argument:

```
<div class="media list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in entries">
<a type="button" ng-click="dial(item.id.$t)">
    <img  ng-src="{{item.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url}}">
</a>
```

But I don't know how to pass it into my tag

`<youtube-list search="search" dial="addTrackFromPicker(???)"></youtube-list>`

I also tried `$parent.addTrackFromPicker` but it didnt work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to pass in your data from your directive, you will need to do it like this:

```
<youtube-list search="search" dial="addTrackFromPicker(data)"></youtube-list>
```

Then, in your template:

```
<div class="media list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in entries">
    <a type="button" ng-click="dial({data: item.id.$t})">
        <img  ng-src="{{item.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url}}">
    </a>
</div>
```

You can use an "argument name" other than `data` if something else makes more sense for your situation. See [Angular's documentation on `scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) for detailed info on how this works.

Comment: Just in case it's not clear it's the naming of the variable that is the important thing here. Otherwise the passed variables will be undefined.

Comment: @SethGunnells: I have to pass two parameters how I can pass with {data:}?

Answer (score 5):

**Isolated Scope:** pass some values from the parent scope to the directives

There’re 3 types of prefixes AngularJS provides

1. "@"   (  Text binding / one-way binding )
2. "="   ( Direct model binding / two-way binding )
3. "&"   ( Behaviour binding / Method binding  )

All these prefixes receives data from the attributes of the directive element.

```
 class="directive"

 name="{{name}}"

 color="color"
```

When the directive encounters a prefix in the scope property, it will look for an attribute ( with same property name ) on directive’s html element

```
 scope : {    
  name: "@"    
 }
```

I've followed this link`http://jsfiddle.net/shidhincr/pJLT8/10/light/`