# Share data from a directive within another isolated scope directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, isolate-scope

I'm trying to take a component approach to my Angular code by writing component style directives, but I have run into a problem.  Below is my html template for the page.  Note that I'm using the [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) tabs directive.

The problem I'm having is that the woSamplesSummary.materialsCount is undefined right under the work-order directive (outside of the tab pane scope), but it displays correctly in the tab pane directive as part of the tab title (within the tab pane scope). So the basic issue is how to share data on a page when using a directive within another isolated scope directive?

```
<work-order wo-id="{{woId}}"></work-order>
<div>Materials Count: {{woSamplesSummary.materialsCount}}</div>

<!--- TABS ------>
<div ng-show="woId" bs-tabs>

    <!--- MATERIALS --->
    <div bs-pane title="Materials ({{woSamplesSummary.materialsCount}})" id="materials">

        <work-order-samples 
            wo-id="{{woId}}" 
            wo-samples-summary="woSamplesSummary" >
        </work-order-samples>
    </div>

    <!--- additional tabs not shown --->

</div>
```

Here's my work-order-samples directive.  I removed most of the logic, but you can see that I setup woSamplesSummary with two-way binding and have bound the properties to the controller, which is all working correctly and has allowed me to move away from using $scope.

```
.directive('workOrderSamples', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'false',
        templateUrl: 'myTemplate',
        scope: { },
        controllerAs: 'wosamplesCtlr',
        bindToController: {
            woId: '@',
            woSamplesSummary: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, myModel) {
            var self = this;
            $attrs.$observe('woId', function(woId) {
                workOrderSamples.find(conditions).then(function () {
                    self.woSamples          = workOrderSamples;
                    self.woSamplesSummary   = {
                        batchCount: workOrderSamples.batches.length,
                        materialsCount: workOrderSamples.list.length }
                });
            });
        }
    };
})
```

So the problem seems to be that the tabs directive is creating an isolated scope, so I am not able to make the data available outside of the tab I'm in.

It seems like there should be a way to make data available from a directive when it's used within other isolated scope directives.  I've tried many different approaches, but without any success.  Assigning the value to $rootScope within my directive does work, but it's just not a good solution (e.g. - if I want to use this directive multiple times on a page).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try making a service?

Comment: Or have you tried $broadcast, $emit communication?

Comment: Hey also this is off topic but consider using the ng-bind attribute instead of using {{}}. It's faster and when there's many things bound to a single document, you might catch a glimpse of the brackets. ng-bind get's around this :]

Comment: I considered both making a service and using $broadcast/$emit, but neither felt like a good approach when all I want to do is break some data out of an isolated scope.  I was hoping for something that would be more obvious in the template.  Instead of the additional coding to create a service or event, why shouldn't I just use $rootScope?  I know in my question I stated that I didn't want to, but still it seems better for breaking data out of a scope than the other options. Is $rootScope a bad idea for Angular 2.0?

Comment: Idk about angular 2.0 but when you create those references on the $rootScope, they are accessible anywhere, and I'm not too sure how the garbage collection process works in that case so it's probably your best bet to stay clear from that polluting solution. The other thing you can try is having one of the directives 'require' another, which would give you access to its controller as a fourth optional param in your link function.

Comment: Here's what I was thinking for $rootScope.  I could add a line in my directive controller which had $rootScope[$attrs.woSamplesSummary] = self.woSamplesSummary;  This would essentially make the two-way bound variable from the directive attribute and instead of just making it available to the parent scope, it would make it available to the rootScope.  Perhaps I could add an extra attribute onto the directive indicating whether two-way bound variables should be published to the parent scope (Angular's default) or the rootScope.  Thoughts?

Comment: I'm unclear on the 'require' option.  If I used that wouldn't it just make the controller logic shared?  Since I use the new constructor with my service wouldn't be dealing with the same object.  Sorry I'm not being very clear because I'm confused on this.

Comment: check this out: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directive-to-directive-communication It doesn't share the controller logic but passes it to the other directive as if it were a service. So w.e you end up calling your ctrl you can reference your logic directly like ctrl.myFunc. That link describes it WAY better than I obviously

Comment: I don't think the 'require' approach will work because in my controller I create a new model object so that I can reuse the directive multiple times on a page, so requiring it in other controllers would create separate model objects.  Sorry, that wasn't clear in my sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of communication in Angular. One of which is to use services. The other is to use $broadcast and $emit/$on.

## Angular Custom Events using $broadcast, $emit, $on.

In your directive I'd start with:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent', data)
```

Then on the receiving end:

```
$rootScope.$on('myEvent', function(e, args){
   // do stuff
});
```

You must also unregister $rootScope listeners to avoid memory leaks. The way you do that is by calling the function that the $on returns and apply it during the scope's $destroy event.

```
var cleanfunction = $rootScope.$on('showLogin', showLoginDialog());

$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
  cleanfunction();
})
```

Comment: I'm just trying to do is to break out of the isolated scope, so why not just use $rootScope? I could add in my directive controller $rootScope[$attrs.woSamplesSummary] = self.woSamplesSummary; This would take the two-way bound variable from the directive attribute and instead of making it available to the parent scope, it would make it available to the rootScope. I could add an optional attribute on the directive indicating that two-way bound variables should be published to the rootScope. Thoughts?

Comment: still not crazy about this approach, but I think it's a better solution overall than the one I proposed below because your solution is independent of scope.

Comment: Just found out too that rootScope variables can be accessed from Isolate scopes.  Just use {{$root.variable}}.  That can be useful to address simple needs. See http://jsfiddle.net/3XT3F/10/

Comment: Noice I didn't know that!

Comment: One of the reasons it's dangerous to use the rootScope is because the data remains there even as you switch pages.  If you have a reasonably sized SPA, then this could become a serious problem.